# Unzip file using .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I want to pass some zipped XML files into SQL Server 2008 which is compatible with .NET 2.0. (implementing c# to be imported as CLR).

I downloaded a .zip file from an API and this .zip file contains several XML files. Is there any way to decompress the get the XML's **using .NET 2.0**? The use of external libraries is not possible.

The export of the file is done by this code:

```
byte[] varbinary = GetStreamFileResult(..);
string tempPath = Path.GetTempPath()+ "temp.zip";
File.WriteAllBytes(tempPath, varbinary); // Requires System.IO
```

In my research I found solution like [this](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/p/6873/23543.aspx) but they are not applicable to my case.

Comment: Is no external software allowed? 7-zip, for example, is free and has a good command line interface

Comment: https://forums.asp.net/t/1076901.aspx?Zip+the+file+in+C+net+2+0+windows+application+

Comment: Frankly, I think you've misunderstood the intended use-case of .NET inside SQL Server; performing http queries and creating zip files seems *very far outside* what you should be doing - it is actually quite horrifying as an observer. You should be doing these things on an *application server* - not in the RDBMS.

Comment: @MarcGravell I understand that CLR are bad practice but the whole system is using SQL-Delphi(don't ask..). This task needs to be scheduled every day and we have big problem with Microsoft Agent. On the other hand the SQL job Agent is very reliable.

Comment: @HoneyBadger The problem is that I cannot guarantee that the system will have 7-zip (or any related) installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In *later versions* of the framework: this is readily available.

In 2.0: there are *external libraries* that expose this, but you say that isn't allowed.

So: if it isn't in the 2.0 framework and you can't use external libraries, you'd have to code a zip decoder from scratch. This is a significant amount of work and is almost certainly not a good idea. It would be a better move to challenge either of the two imposed limitations. Or: stop trying to run application code inside the database (that isn't what it is intended for).

Comment: *This is a significant amount of work* ... in the 6 to 8 weeks range ...

Comment: @rene I see what you did there :)

Comment: Well, technically you wouldn't have to code it from scratch. You could copy and paste the code from an open source project with a permissive license, so it is possible without a *significant* amount of work. But  I totally agree that all other options presented here and in the comments would be far better than trying to unzip inside of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

If upgrading to a higher version of .NET Framework isn't possible and neither is referencing a 3rd party library, your next best option would be to find an open source compression library project with a permissive license and then copy and paste the bits from it that are required to decompress your zip file.