# Unzip files with SQL

Tags: sql-server, zip, unzip

I can unzip files using only SQL by the following command:

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'C:\Progra~1\7-Zip\7z.exe e "Path\t.zip" -o"OutputPath"'
```

But I would like this procedure to be installed into different servers and I cannot guarantee that all of them will have 7z installed.

Could I:

1. Unzip without third party software?
2. Take as input the default software for zip which each system uses?
3. Include into SQL-Server 2008 an installation of 7z (since it is free)?

Comment: This sounds like something is going on that is not a great design. Once you have to use unzip in t-sql something is bit off center. Maybe in an SSIS package I could see this. But then needing this functionality on multiple servers is another indication there is probably a better approach to what you are really trying to do.

Comment: @SeanLange I have a stream from an API which is a zip containing several .XML files. What I am trying to do is take the XML files and insert them into the representative tables.

Comment: t-sql is not the right tool for this. You should build this as a service and then you can use a programming language like c# or whatever.

Comment: @SeanLange as I asked on another question here there is easy way to do in C# and I am just wandering if there is a way with SQL. Question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48459097/unzip-file-using-net-2-0

Comment: And much like the comments on your other question this is a horrific way to approach this problem. Unzipping files with sql server is like putting together furniture with nothing other than screws and a hammer. Sure you can force it together but the finished product is not going to be very safe or stable.

Comment: execute 7zip from SQL Server!!!. This is the worse thing I've ever seen :) And you know that xp_cmdshell is disabled by default because of security?. at lease you can use CLR

Comment: @FLICKER I know xc_cmdshell is disabled by default. But on the system I am working is enabled due to other reasons. I would like to do so with CLR but as I mentioned on commends before is not so easy.